# How to Query Mongoose db in express.js with "like" command /"string"/l?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am querying Mongoose db with a search, where the title is the "customTitle" from the URL.

The search works well if I search for all items, e.g.
`Article.find(err, foundArticles) =>`, but I am getting an empty query response to `Article.find({title:/customTitle/i}, (err, foundArticles) => {`

I'd like to get a response with all items, that contains "customTitle" variable in any record.

```js
app.route("/:customTitle")
.get(function(req, res){
  const customTitle = _.capitalize(req.params.customTitle);
  Article.find({title:/customTitle/i}, (err, foundArticles) => {
  if (!err){
    res.send(foundArticles);
    console.log(typeof customTitle +" ", customTitle);
    console.log(foundArticles);
  } else {
    res.send(err);
  }
});
```

What is the problem here, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found, that I can use RegExp of Mongoose and JavaScript

Mongoose RegExp that works:

```js
app.route("/:customTitle")
  .get(function(req, res) {
    const customTitle = _.capitalize(req.params.customTitle);
    Article.find({ title: {$regex: customTitle, $options:'i'}}, (err, foundArticles) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(foundArticles);
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      }
  });
```

And JavaScript RegExp that works:

```js
  app.route("/:customTitle")
    .get(function(req, res) {
      const customTitle = _.capitalize(req.params.customTitle);
      const rx = new RegExp(customTitle, 'i');
      Article.find({title:rx}, (err, foundArticles) => {
        if (!err) {
          res.send(foundArticles);
        } else {
          res.send(err);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the regex using `new RegExp`.  You are searching for the literal string `customTitle`.

For example:

```
const rx = new RegExp(customTitle, 'i')
query.find({title:rx})
```

Comment: Could you please check what else is wrong there? I'm getting still empty response. Thank you

Comment: You might have characters that need escaping.  Post your error.

Comment: Also, hardcode a simple string in the regex instead of using input from query, and see if it works.

Comment: Ok, both work now, so I edited the answer, and I leave it here for others. Thanks!